# C++ Boost.Asio Segmentation Fault on async_write while accessing write-method through shared_ptr

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, boost-asio, shared-ptr

I created a static map that holds several Sessions of connected clients.

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Session>> Communication::m_appSockets;
```

The Listener that accepts incomming clients is implemented in the Communication class.

```
class Communication : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Communication>
{
private:
  boost::asio::io_context m_ioc;
  boost::asio::io_context::work m_work;
  boost::asio::streambuf m_buffer;
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor m_acceptor;
  std::thread m_senderThread;
  std::thread m_ioThread;

public:
  static std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Session>> m_appSockets;

  Communication(uint16_t t_port);

  void accept();

  void doAccept();

  void senderThread();
};
```

After accepting a client the method "doAccept" creates a session object and moves the socket like this

```
  m_acceptor.async_accept(
    [this](boost::system::error_code t_ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket t_socket) {
      if (!t_ec)
      {
            m_appSockets.emplace(std::pair<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Session>>(
              "app0", std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(t_socket))));
            m_appSockets["app0"]->start();
      }
      accept();
    });
```

Session.h looks like this:

```
class Session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session>
{
private:
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket m_socket;
  boost::asio::streambuf m_buffer;

public:

  Session(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket t_socket);

  void write(std::string &t_msg);
  void doWrite(std::string &t_msg);
  void start();
...
};
```

void start() is used for starting the async read on the socket, which is working fine.
A session object is created this way:

```
Session::Session(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket t_socket) : m_socket(std::move(t_socket))
{}
```

What I need to do for my implementation is to access the write-method of session through the shared_ptr in the map of Communication.h.
I tried it the following way

```
void Communication::senderThread()
{
  for (;;)
  {
    .... 
    //blocking until queue holds a message
    std::string buf = *message from queue*//pseudo code
    m_appSockets["app0"].get()->write(buf);

  }
}
```

A senderthread blocks until a message is available in a queue which will be forwarded to the write method of session

The write-method can be called but as soon as i try an operation on any member of the session it gives me a segmentation fault:

```
void Session::write(std::string &t_msg)
{
//here it crashes
  m_socket.get_executor().context().post(std::bind(&Session::doWrite, shared_from_this(), t_msg));
}

void Session::doWrite(std::string &t_msg)
{
  boost::asio::async_write(
    m_socket, boost::asio::buffer(t_msg),
    std::bind(&Session::onWrite, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
}
```

It feels like the Session object runs out of scope as soon as I enter its method. I have tried creating dummy members in Session which all gave the same segmentation fault when accessing them. 
Am I getting the shared_ptr/object lifetime wrong at some point?

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT 1:
Running gdb ./programm.out core gave me this:

> Thread 2 "programm.out" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   [Switching to Thread 0x7ffff58f1700 (LWP 5651)] 0x0000555555605932 in
>   Session::write (this=0x0, 
>       t_msg="{\"destination\":\"app0\"}")
>       at /usr/Sources/Session.cpp:58 58   std::cout << dummyMember << std::endl;

I added a member to Session (int dummyMember{5};).

How can it be that this is pointing to 0x0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below line is suspicious

```
  boost::asio::buffer(t_msg)
```

`asio::buffer` returns object which holds a pointer to the content of string and length of string (a copy of `t_msg` is not created). You have to be careful when using `asio::buffer` with asynchronous operations because its return type is pair *(pointer,length)* to string, it doesn't extend the lifetime of string.

`async_write` function returns immediately and we don't know when handler will be called, so you have to make sure that `msg` is valid until handler is called.

```
  for(;;)
  {
    std::string buf = *message from queue*//pseudo code
    m_appSockets["app0"].get()->write(buf);

    // if you want to send original buf string
    // before this loop ends all asynchronous operation writing buf must be complete
  }
```

If your goal is to send `msg` you have missed to use `ref` wrapper, because `bind` takes parameters by value by default.

```
std::bind(&Session::doWrite, shared_from_this(), t_msg) // make copy of t_msg
```

above creates callback which holds copy of `t_msg`. 
When this callback is called copy of `t_msg` is passed into `boost::asio::buffer(t_msg)` in `Session::doWrite`. Probably, before callback created by `std::bind(&Session::onWrite, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)` is executed string copy is destroyed and `buffer` points to deleted data.

You can rewrite `Session::write` method using `std::ref`:

```
m_socket.get_executor().context().post(std::bind(&Session::doWrite, shared_from_this(), std::ref(t_msg)));
```

and ensure that all asynchronous operations which write this string are complete until `for` loop ends in `senderThread`. Or you need to find another way to hold `t_msg` string while asynchronous operations are executed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Indeed this is a problem I have. I adapted my code but this doesn't fix the segmentation fault. The error occurs already in in write() before doWrite() is reached.
For example: If I add a member int dummy{5}; to session and try access it through a getter method at the beginning of write() I already get the segmentation fault.

Comment: Thanks for your answer which would have let to mistakes later on.
I accessed the map in a seperate thread before the async accept created the session in the map, as we got the "this" pointing to 0x0 in the core dump.
Making sure the object is created first fixed the problem.